# Set background of rows in dynamically created grid

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, grid

I have to make a table for WP8.SDk.

I am using a grid for this purpose. I have created a dynamic grid of rows and columns.

Now I want to set a background image to make header different..

My C# code is here.

```
private void table_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Creation of Grid
    Grid tablegrid = new Grid();
    tablegrid.Height = double.NaN;
    tablegrid.Width = 454;
    tablegrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 66, 0, 0);
    tablegrid.ShowGridLines = true;
    tablegrid.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    tablegrid.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    //Table Rows and Columns Definition
    string[] tablerow = new string[] { "Submit Report", "Something", "New" };
    string[] tablecol = new string[] { "Mansab", "Arsal", "Ali" };

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < tablerow.Length; i++)
    {
        RowDefinition gridrows = new RowDefinition();
        gridrows.Height = new GridLength(66);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            var brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Images/top_bar_bg.png", UriKind.Relative));

            //gridrows.Background = brush;   //This not works
        }

        tablegrid.RowDefinitions.Insert(i, gridrows);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < tablecol.Length; j++)
    {
        ColumnDefinition gridCol = new ColumnDefinition();
        tablegrid.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(j, gridCol);
    }
    tablegrid.ShowGridLines = true;
    ContentPanel.Children.Add(tablegrid);
}
```

My table look like this:

```
http://www.4shared.com/download/SlNX8mbpba/Table.PNG
```

but I have to make something like this:

```
http://www.4shared.com/download/j-qT-kGVce/table2.PNG
```

How can I specify the background of each row dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by doing this.

```
    private void table_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Creation of Grid
        Grid tablegrid = new Grid();
        tablegrid.Height = double.NaN;
        tablegrid.Width = double.NaN;
        tablegrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 66, 0, 0);
       // tablegrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        tablegrid.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        tablegrid.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;


        //Table Rows and Columns Definition
        string[] tablerow = new string[] { "Submit Report","Arsal","AA","Mansab","a","e"};
        string[] tablecol = new string[] { "Mansab","Ali","Aly","Ayaz" };


        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < tablerow.Length; i++)
        {
            RowDefinition gridrows = new RowDefinition();
            gridrows.Height = new GridLength(66);
            tablegrid.RowDefinitions.Insert(i, gridrows);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < tablecol.Length; j++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition gridCol = new ColumnDefinition();
            tablegrid.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(j, gridCol);
        }

     // Setting background Image for all rows and columns Dynamically

        int k = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < tablecol.Length; k++)
        {
            Border brd = new Border();
            brd.Height = 66;
            brd.Width = 460;
            brd.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            Grid.SetRow(brd, 0);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(brd, tablecol.Length);
            tablegrid.Children.Add(brd);
            var brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Images/top_bar_bg.png", UriKind.Relative));
            brd.Background = brush;
        }
        int l;
        for (l = 0; l < tablecol.Length; l++)
        {
            Border brd = new Border();
            brd.Height = 66;
            brd.Width = 460;
            brd.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            Grid.SetRow(brd, 1);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(brd, tablecol.Length);
            tablegrid.Children.Add(brd);
            var brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Images/table_row_blue.png", UriKind.Relative));
            brd.Background = brush;
        }
      ContentPanel.Children.Add(tablegrid);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of ColumnHeaderStyle property for setting the column header differently from the content rows. Can you specify the need of setting the BG Color of each row everytime. If not a specific need, can use AlternateRowStyle property of the datagrid.

Comment: I am not able to use datagrid for windows phone 8 sdk. here is just grid. and I am trying to use this as a table. So background image for header is necessary ..  If Iwould able to do this for header then I can put in all rows and columns.. but here i am not able.. so could you solve this..?

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, a `Grid` has no concept of a 'cell', so you cannot colour the background of a 'cell'. Instead of this, you can put something into your cell(s) and set the background of that control. For example, you could colour the `TextBlock.Background` property of the 'header' text.

Alternatively, you could put a `StackPanel` or similar into the cell and put the `TextBlock` inside that and then colour the `StackPanel.Background` property.

---

UPDATE >>>

Personally, I'd say that you've picked a gnarly method to try to implement your requirements. I think that you'd find it much easier to use a `Grid` just for the header row and a `ListBox` with an `ItemsTemplate` containing another `Grid` for the data rows. You could use the [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to keep the columns in line with each other.

For you current 'image' problem, you could even display an `Image` above the `ListBox` and then overlay the header `Grid` on top of it.

Comment: yes you are right i think....I did it with a TextBlock..and set background color.  But i have to put image in all header row...I can't add picture in each cell by adding a TextBlock..this would be horrifying.